# Git - Merging remote branch with uncommited changes and choosing theirs

Tags: git

I've ran into a small problem regarding working with git - I'd like to merge my current branch (let's call it `foo`) with a target branch (`bar`). However, I have uncommitted changes on `foo`, that I'd rather not commit and those changes are conflicting with the changes on `bar`.
What I want to achieve is merge those branches and when it comes to conflicting files, pick the file from `bar`.

I've tried using

```
git merge origin/%TARGET_BRANCH% --strategy-option theirs
```

However that seems to just throw an error "Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge" and abort.

Is there a way to achieve that using just git commands, or do I have to create some kind of a workaround (e.g. parsing all of the conflicting files, resetting them and then trying the merge again)?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: You need to do *something* with your uncommitted changes before you do other stuff that would clobber them. The normal options are: commit them, stash them, or delete them. @TheIceBear offers [a solution with committing them](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68746990/184546).

Answer (score 2):

Create a branch from `foo` and call it `foo-2`.

```
git checkout foo
git checkout -b foo-2
```

Commit your uncommitted changes to `foo-2`. Then merge `foo` with `bar` and solve any conflicts. That will merge the `foo` to `bar` without your current uncommitted edits.

```
git checkout bar
git merge foo
```

The you can decide to merge `foo-2` to `bar` whenever you are ready to do so. You can select which version of a conflicted file while doing so.

Answer (score 0):

> I'd like to merge my current branch (let's call it `foo`) with a target branch (bar). However, I have uncommitted changes on `foo` ...

You can't do that.

More precisely, `git merge` itself will not let you do this in any case where actual merging is required (as you've seen).  Some of the merge internals *will* let you do that, but *do not do it*.  It is a recipe for (irrecoverable) disaster.  The `git stash` code will do this sometimes, which is one reason I try to discourage people from using `git stash`.  When it works, it's fine!  But when it goes wrong, there's no recovery fallback.

See [TheIceBear's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68746990/1256452) for one method.  Another is, as I mentioned, using `git stash`—but this just makes a commit.  (Actually, it makes *two* commits, but you'll subsequently use only one of the two; the other one is a "junk commit".  Both commits will get dropped and, eventually, garbage collected later.)  The only thing special about the commit(s) made by `git stash` are that they are on *no* branch, and, later, that `git stash apply` uses `git merge` unsafely.  I prefer the first method, of making an explicit commit that you can find with a branch name like `foo-2`.